# Adding custom icons in leaflet to geojson file

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I got the following code

```
var Iconcm = L.icon({
iconUrl: 'customicon.png',
iconSize: [25, 25],
iconAnchor: [22, 94],
popupAnchor: [-10, -95]
});



$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "pc.geojson",
        success: function(data) {
                L.geoJson(data, {
                    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                }).addTo(map);
        }
     }).error(function() {});


        function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
      var lines = ('Field1: ' + feature.properties.f1 + '<br>' + 'Field2: ' + feature.properties.f2)

            layer.bindPopup(lines);
        };
```

I want to be able to use the `Iconcm` instead of the default blue marker. I've tried just about every way to do it that I found on the internet to no avail. I'm new at javascript and even more at AJAX. The above code is the only way my geojson file actually worked so I would prefer to keep it that way. In addition, in the future I would like to be able to have different icons depending on the feature properties in one field. So for example if `feature.properties.f3` is `Type1` be `customicon1`, `Type2` is `customicon2`, and so on. Is there a way to do that too? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method [setIcon](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#marker-seticon) you can use.

You want to test you only call it if the layer is actually a L.Marker

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
    layer.setIcon(Iconcm)
  }
// ...
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! For those that may use this, I added the code above the lines part.

Answer (score 0):

L.geoJSON provides `pointToLayer` to create custom markers, see example at
https://leafletjs.com/SlavaUkraini/examples/geojson/

```
var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#ff7800",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
};

L.geoJSON(someGeojsonFeature, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Instead of using the circle marker, you could also create a marker with a custom icon.

Comment: Not to sound cynical, but what exactly is meant by ```someGeojsonFeature```? Even though that's from the Leaflet help pages it assumes the reader is supposed to know what that means.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, it's a while ago I used it, but the docs (https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) point at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946 which says "GeoJSON is a format for encoding a variety of geographic data structures using JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) [RFC7159].  A GeoJSON object may represent a region of space (a Geometry), a spatially bounded entity (a Feature), or a list of Features (a FeatureCollection)."